# What type of View is that slim bar above the editor in Xcode?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, interface-builder, nsview

I want to use the same sort of UI style of Xcode has right above the editor pane, as show below:

### [image: Xcode screenshot]

I've browsed through all the Views in Interface Builder and can't figure out what type of view this is.  At this point I'm merely referring to the bar itself; not to the controls nested inside the bar, though I will be adding dropdowns in the same way as this.

What type of view should I be looking for?

TextMate uses one along the bottom of the editor too, which provides similar controls:

[image: TextMate screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see:

`$(DEVELOPER_ROOT)/Applications/Utilities/Accessibility Tools/Accessibility Inspector.app`

just open Accessibility Inspector.app and move the cursor over the views you're interested in for details (you may need to enable accessibility options in system preferences.app).

it's also helpful to press cmd+F7 to lock onto a view and then to inspect its children.

so... 3 primary options:

1) if you want drag & drop convenience, you can simulate it with a Gradient Button

2) or you can use the button with a custom image in the button to achieve something closer

3) or just create a new view subclass and render it using a CGGradient or NSGradient

Comment: Interesting, this seems like a really useful tool!  Thanks so much :)

Comment: yes, it is. you're welcome. also, i added 3 easy ways to simulate the look, but most of the work will actually be just adding/implementing all the subcontrols. good luck!

Comment: Cheers, playing around a bit with this controls now.